# flutter user generated in app purchasing system like udemy

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, payment-processing, android-inapp-purchase

Im building an app which users can plan events and sell tickets. so i want to build a system which lets users define in app purchase products and sell it to other users and as apps owner i will cut my comission. My problem is users can't define in app purchase products and apple pay or G pay is unavailable in my country. When i bought a course from udemy on mobile, i saw the course was an in app purchase product. So how they do this and how can i do same in flutter? If this is not possible, are there any way to take users payment info just like in app purchase for send to endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a 3D payment provider.
try integrating [strip](https://stripe.com/) for example in your application

Comment: I know i can use a payment gate way but I'm asking how does udemy handle this and if there is a way to take payment info from user like it is a native payment